# problema para aplicar toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que aplicar toFixed(2) en este contexto pero no se como hacerlo.

```
<p id="cuotas" class="card-title one-line-title">6x ${data.price/6}</p>
```

El codigo entero es

```
const mostrarProducto = function (data){
  let infoProducto =`
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 my-2">
   <div class="card h-100">
     <img src= "${data.pictures[0].url}" class="card-img-top">
     <div class="card-body">
     <h4 class="card-text">$${data.price}</h4>
      <p id="cuotas" class="card-title one-line-title">6x ${data.price/6}</p>
      <p id="titulo" class="card-title one-line-title">${data.title}</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
`;
  producto.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', infoProducto);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es tan simple como encerrar la expresión entre paréntesis y luego llamar a la función.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let data = {price: 100},
  html = `<p>6x ${(data.price/6).toFixed(2)}</p>`

console.log(html);
```